# how to avoid command errors in shell script execution

Tags: bash, shell, ksh

I have a block of code in a shell script as follows..

```
    run_checks()
    {
    # Check if program is already running
    if ! mkdir /tmp/aisync.lock; then
      printf "Failed to aquire lock.\n" >&2
      exit 1
    fi
    trap 'rm -rf /tmp/aisync.lock' EXIT
    }
```

It basically checks if aisync.lock exists and fails if it does, to prevent multiple instances of the same shell script from running.

However, if I run this from the console i get..

```
    # syncai.sh
    mkdir: 0653-358 Cannot create /tmp/aisync.lock.
    /tmp/aisync.lock: Do not specify an existing file.
    Failed to aquire lock.
```

Is there a way to avoid the error?

```
    mkdir: 0653-358 Cannot create /tmp/aisync.lock.
    /tmp/aisync.lock: Do not specify an existing file.
```

So that it looks more clean when I run it from command line.. I know that if I cron it I can send everything to /dev/null which I intend to do.. but running manually from console how can I remove those errors from printing out?

Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at `man lockfile` !

Comment: # man lockfile
Manual entry for lockfile not found or not installed.
Running AIX 7.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the middle part of your script like this:

```
if ! mkdir /tmp/aisync.lock 2>/dev/null; then
  printf "Failed to aquire lock.\n" >&2
  exit 1
fi
```

That way the error message from `mkdir` will be thrown away. At the same time the behavior is unchanged, `mkdir` still fails, so the condition in the `if` will evaluate true and the script will exit with 1.

Comment: Great answer, but technically, `mkdir` still throws an error (we still get the expected non-zero exit code), but the `2> /dev/null` discards the default *message*, which we don't care for.

Comment: Thanks @HenkLangeveld you're right, I didn't like that sentence either. I corrected it now.

Answer (score 0):

A reliable [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) lock function :

```
LOCK()
{
    LOCKDIR="/tmp/${0##*/}-lock-$1"
    PIDFILE="${LOCKDIR}/PID"

    if mkdir "${LOCKDIR}" &>/dev/null; then
            echo "$$" >"${PIDFILE}"
            trap 'rm -rf "${LOCKDIR}"' 0
            trap 'echo "killed by a signal." >&2; exit' 1 2 3 15
    else
            OTHERPID="$(cat "${PIDFILE}")"
            if ! kill -0 $OTHERPID &>/dev/null; then
                    echo "removing stale lock of nonexistant PID ${OTHERPID}" >&2
                    rm -rf "${LOCKDIR}"
                    exit
            fi
    fi
}
```